# How can I scroll to a page element in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a long jQuery mobile page and would like to scroll to an element halfway down this page after the page loads.

So far I've tried a few things, the most successful being:

```
jQuery(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
  var target;
  // if there's an element with id 'current_user'
  if ($("#current_user").length > 0) {
    // find this element's offset position
    target = $("#current_user").get(0).offsetTop;
    // scroll the page to that position
    return $.mobile.silentScroll(target);
  }
});
```

This works but then the page position is reset when the DOM is fully loaded. Can anyone suggest a better approach?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try binding to the `pagecreate` event instead.

Comment: yes - and pageInit. No luck :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event you're looking for is "pageshow".

Comment: This kind of works and kind of doesn't. I'm trying to call     $.mobile.silentScroll(1000) when the page loads. By sticking it inside a $("div").live("pageshow", function() {}); it works but then resets the position as soon as the page is done loading... any ideas?

Comment: Hmmm.. pageshow is only supposed to fire once the page switching operations are completed. I wonder if the silentScroll is the issue.  Try this:$(document).scrollTop(56);

Comment: If that still doesn't work, you might have to do a brief timeout like... setTimeout(function(){$.mobile.silentScroll(1000)},100);

Answer (score 10):

A bit late, but I think I have a reliable solution with no need for `setTimeout()`. After a quick look into the code, it seems that JQM 1.2.0 issues a `silentScroll(0)` on `window.load` for chromeless viewport on iOS. See `jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js`, line 9145:

```
    // window load event
    // hide iOS browser chrome on load
    $window.load( $.mobile.silentScroll );
```

What happens is that this conflicts with applicative calls to `silentScroll()`. Called too early, the framework scrolls back to top. Called too late, the UI flashes.

The solution is to bind a one-shot handler to the `'silentscroll'` event that calls `window.scrollTo()` directly (`silentScroll()` is little more than an asynchronous `window.scrollTo()` anyway). That way, we capture the first JQM-issued `silentScroll(0)` and scroll to our position immediately.

For example, here is the code I use for deep linking to named elements (be sure to disable ajax load on inbound links with `data-ajax="false"`). Known anchor names are `#unread` and `#p<ID>`. The header is fixed and uses the `#header` ID.

```
$(document).bind('pageshow',function(e) {
    var $anchor;
    console.log("location.hash="+location.hash);
    if (location.hash == "#unread" || location.hash.substr(0,2) == "#p") {
        // Use anchor name as ID for the element to scroll to.
        $anchor = $(location.hash);
    }
    if ($anchor) {
        // Get y pos of anchor element.
        var pos = $anchor.offset().top;

        // Our header is fixed so offset pos by height.
        pos -= $('#header').outerHeight();

        // Don't use silentScroll() as it interferes with the automatic 
        // silentScroll(0) call done by JQM on page load. Instead, register
        // a one-shot 'silentscroll' handler that performs a plain
        // window.scrollTo() afterward.
        $(document).bind('silentscroll',function(e,data) {
            $(this).unbind(e);
            window.scrollTo(0, pos);
        });
    }
});
```

No more UI flashes, and it seems to work reliably.

Answer (score 0):

I was digging a lot this issue, also at [jQuery mobile official forum](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-anchor-linking).

Currently it seems that there is no solution (at least for me).

I tried different events (mobileinit, pageshow) and different functions (silentscroll, scrolltop) as suggested above, but, as a result, I always have page scrolled until all images and html is finished loading, when page is scrolled to top again!

Partial and not really efficient solution is using a timer as suggested in comment to [sgliser's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7898321/447356); unfortunately with a timeout is difficult to know when page will be fully loaded and if scroll happened *before* that, it will scroll back to top at the end of load, while if it happens *too long after* page has fully loaded, the user is already scrolling page manually, and further automated scroll will create confusion.

Additionally, would be useful to have silentscroll or other function to address a specific id or class and not plain pixels, because with different browsers, resolutions and devices it may give different and not correct positioning of the scroll.

Hope someone will find a smarter and more efficient solution than this.