# jQuery Mobile anchor links without ajax not loading

Tags: jquery-mobile, hyperlink, anchor

I have jQuery Mobile ajax navigation fully disabled, like so:

```
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
    });
```

This is working perfectly EXCEPT, anchor / hash links do not work as they normally do outside of JQM.

When the page loads you are at the top of the page (if it loads slowly enough you'll see load at the anchor point, then jump to the top). Either way you end up at the top of the page not at the anchor link as you should. Is there any good workaround for this? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you're running a number of jQuery plugins, including something called "scrollTo". Have you made sure that the issue is jQuery Mobile's fault by removing the other scripts?

Comment: You have "something" that forces the page to go to the top after its fully loaded.

Comment: @Jasper - Yes, definitely tried removing all other scripts, same result. The Net is full of various folks with the same issue, including -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863114/jquery-mobile-page-wont-load-to-anchor-tag-on-link-from-separate

Comment: Yea, it seems this problem is common, however I worked out an example that could somehow give you a rough idea how to work around this dilemma. JQM focus on the top of the page because it has `tabindex="0"`. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/zsNDV/

Comment: here's another different example http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/89fyf/

Comment: Thanks @Omar I appreciate it! I'm not sure this would work when coming from an external page. But it gave me some more ideas to search for, I think I found a solution (posted below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fix is just slightly modified code from this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14286613/1462775) so that it should work for all anchor links, not just specific ones. I put this script at the end of my `<head>` element.

```
$(document).bind('pageshow',function(e) {
    var $anchor;
    $anchor = $(location.hash);
    if ($anchor) {
        // Get y pos of anchor element.
        var pos = $anchor.offset().top;

        // Don't use silentScroll() as it interferes with the automatic 
        // silentScroll(0) call done by JQM on page load. Instead, register
        // a one-shot 'silentscroll' handler that performs a plain
        // window.scrollTo() afterward.
        $(document).bind('silentscroll',function(e,data) {
            $(this).unbind(e);
            window.scrollTo(0, pos);
        });
    }
});
```